# MongoDB — How to sort lookup based on matching field?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my Mongo database, I have two collections — `speakers` and `speeches`, and I'm able to "join" them (getting a speaker's speeches) using the following code block:

```
// I've already found the 'speaker' in the database
db.collection('speakers').aggregate([{
    $match: { "uuid": speaker.uuid } },
    { $lookup: {
        from: "speeches",
        localField: "uuid",
        foreignField: "speaker_id",
        as: "speeches" } }
]).toArray();
```

It works well, but I'd like to sort the speeches array by a `date` field or a `title` field, but nothing I do seems to make it happen. None of the examples I've seen here have done what I need them to do. I've tried adding `{ $sort: { "speech.title": -1 } }` after the `$lookup` block, but it did nothing. Is this even possible?

Comment: what is your mongo version ?

Comment: It's version 4.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) pipeline variant available from 3.6.

```
{"$lookup":{
  "from":"speeches",
  "let":{"uuid":"$uuid"},
  "pipeline":[
    {"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$$uuid","$speaker_id"]}}},
    {"$sort":{"title":1}}
  ],
  "as":"speeches"
}}
```

Comment: This is definitely working, but it's getting all speeches for all speakers. I'm trying to get speeches for a single speaker which I've already found in the database. How can I use that specific `speaker.uuid` to limit the lookup?

Comment: Just replace your lookup stage  with this lookup. Rest all stays as is.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then. I get the speaker like this:

`var speaker = db.collection('speakers').findOne({ full_name: "Speaker Name" });`

and if I leave the `$match: { "uuid": speaker.uuid },` stage in (before the new lookup), I get an error saying `MongoError: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.` Without the above `$match` stage (but with the new lookup), I get every speaker's speeches.

Comment: yeah it looks like your pipeline stages are not formatted correctly. Can you show me the query with all stages ?

Comment: Here's a link to a screen grab https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qkw2e71isafufx/Screenshot%202018-08-16%2017.37.15.jpg?dl=0

Comment: const speaker = await db.collection('speakers').findOne({
            full_name: "Gordon B. Hinckley"
          });
          
          const books = await db.collection('speakers').aggregate([{
            // $match: { "uuid": speaker.uuid },
            "$lookup":{
              "from":"speeches",
              "let":{"uuid":"$uuid"},
              "pipeline":[
                {"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$$uuid","$speaker_id"]}}},
                {"$sort":{"title":1}}
              ],
              "as":"speeches"
            }
          }]).toArray();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178165/discussion-between-se-puede-dev-and-veeram).